# Copy and paste an row and bullets in table layout

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

If you scroll to the bottom of this page: https://www.careercup.com/resume

You will see a link to this word template: https://www.careercup.com/static_html/Gayle_McDowell_CareerCup_Sample_Resume.doc

The Employment section in the template has 4 entries, I'd like to create a 5th entry under Employment. (I'm defining an entry as a row with title/company/dates PLUS the bullets under that row). However, when I try to duplicate one of the existing employment entries by copy and pasting, I bullets from the original entry get deleted.

What's the best way to create an additional entry for example under the Employment section?

Comment: What version of Word are you using? Are you using a Windows based version or a Mac version? How to access the methods for Pasting copied Table Rows vary by platform.

Comment: I'm using Word for Mac Version 15.41. (On mac high sierra 10.13.3)

Comment: Please *describe* your problem.  External links can break, and people aren’t going to download and open files from an unknown person.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy the last two rows from the Employment group.
2. Establish a new selection point at the end of the last row, next to
   the end of cell marker, in the Employment group.
3. From Mac Word's ribbon choose the Paste Menu and there you will find
   the Insert Rows control.
4. Now edit the 5th element.

If the above does not work for you it is because your version of Mac Office is way out-of-date.